# Example of a gherkin subscenario

Tags: gherkin

I have to make some scenarios using gherkin, but then the term sub-scenario came. I can't picture in my mind how a sub-scenario would be. Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: Where did you hear of sub-scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gherkin does not natively support subscenarios, however the specification you may have been tasked with might need breaking down into several scenarios in order to conform to the "Given, When, Then" workflow. Try and dissect the information you HAVE been given into basic deterministic processes, and construct a scenario for each one.

Don't forget that if you're running Gherkin through Cucumber it will execute all the scenarios in a .feature file in the order they are written, so as long as your step definitions are set up in such a way to work with the same objects across scenarios then there wouldn't be an issue.

In summary, I think subscenario is a misnomer here, as it is not a feature of Gherkin and does not fit in to the BDD workflow.